# Docker installed in wsl2 without docker desktop not starting with sudo service docker start

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing docker in wsl2 without docker desktop, and using sudo service docker start, we receive a success message, as shown below:

```
 sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                       [ OK ]
```

But when we run dockerd manually with sudo dockerd, we can find our error, as shown below:

```
ERRO[2022-08-30T09:32:39.000282429-04:00] failed to initialize a tracing processor "otlp"  error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin"
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, we need to append in /etc/default/docker (ubuntu):

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"
```

or

run dockerd as shown below:

```
sudo dockerd --iptables=false
```

Comment: I experienced the same error, and using the `--iptables` command line option worked.  Using an Ubuntu distribution version 22.04.  I did not have this problem last year (mid June 2022) though, and then I had the same Ubuntu version.  Is it because I am using a newer version of Docker?